# Populate Listbox from a table having a XML column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml

Have landed in a problem, which I am tryin to work since a day.
I have a table having a varchar column and a XML column.The schema is below:

```
create table dbo.StandardView(
Name varchar(50),
Fields xml)
```

I inserted a record as below:

```
insert into dbo.StandardView
values('Standard',N'&lt;fieldname&gt;FirstName,SecondName,ThirdName&lt;/fieldname&gt;')
```

I need to populate a listbox with the entities as follows:

```
FirstName
SecondName
ThirdName
```

The code to populate the listbox written is as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateValues();
        }
    }

public void PopulateValues()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dbo.StandardView", xconn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    lstBox.DataSource = dt;
    lstBox.DataTextField = dt.Columns[1].ToString();
    lstBox.DataValueField = dt.Columns[1].ToString();
    lstBox.DataBind();

}
```

The above code puts the whole xml column in the listbox in a string format and its pretty evident.

I tried some xmlserializer,deserializer and xmlreader stuffs but wasn't able to populate the listbox accordingly.

Experts please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with the properties FirstName, SecondName, ThirdName and when you extract the xml column then create a list of this class and populate the list with the xml data then bind the list to the listbox.

Comment: I will try this stuff and will update the thread..Thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your XML, but if the data was like this:

```
<Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <SecondName>Smith</SecondName>
    <ThirdName>Rowle</ThirdName>
</Person>
```

you create an object like this:

```
[XmlRoot()]
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string ThirdName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can get it to work with the `XMLSerializer` class.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
Person p = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()));
```

You can then easily bind your person object to your list, or to whatever else you need to bind it to. Notice that I am binding only the second column of the first row for testing purposes.

Comment: Escano:Thanks for the reply mate..but a XML tag can have multiple items..<A>Hi,Hello,Cool</A>...Anyways I will have a go with your reply and the reply posted above by Azhar and lets see..